# Webcam service for a website: user to user, directly, is it possible?

Tags: flash, streaming, webcam

I wonder wether on a website like chatroulette for example, the streaming video is going directly from user to user or wether it is going through a server.

In other words I wonder wether it is possible to offer a webcam service on a website, so that the streaming video goes directly from user to user, without overloading the system. If it is possible, what technology makes it possible? Flash?

Thank you ;)

Comment: @Anthony: I LOL'd and LOL'd at your comment +1 from me.... :D

Comment: @tommieb75: thank you, my brother showed me chatroulette and out of the 10 webcam's he visited, not one was even slightly appropriate.

Comment: I'm not planning on making a chatroulette, but a community website with a free video chat service. I talked about chatroulette because it's the most known webcam website ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen any "user to user" without some kind of backend co-ordination.

I reckon your best bet would be to use something like flash media server and flash